# To solve chess with deep RL and MCTS, how should I represent the input (the state) to a neural network?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, monte-carlo-tree-search, chess, state-spaces

I'm wanting to build a NN that can create a policy for each possible state. I want to combine this with MCTS to eliminate randomness so when expansion occurs, I can get the probability of the move to winning.

I am confident (I believe) in how to code the neural network, but the input shape is the hardest part here. I am firstly wanting to try with 2 player chess and then expand to 3 player chess.

What is the best vector/matrix to use for the input in a chess game? How should the input be fed into a neural network to output the most promising move from the position? In addition, what format should it look like (i.e [001111000], etc.)?

Comment: Coincidentally I just started coding this up a few days ago, and I had the same question. I highly recommend reading the AlphaZero paper, they give a decent description of how they encoded the states.